# How to share xml_content in Terraform API Management resource

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

We are creating our API management instance and associated endpoints through Terraform. All our API endpoints (close to a hundred) share the same policy logic for routing the request to an Azure function.

An example policy is like so -

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" 
"api_put_policy" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.my_api.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.my_api.name
  operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.my_api.operation_id

xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Key") == "password")">
            <set-backend-service base-url="${data.azurerm_function_app.MyFunctionApp.default_hostname}" />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Key") != null)">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-body>An incorrect Key header has been passed in the request</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-backend-service base-url="${other-route-variable}" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

So we have the same XML_content being used on every API endpoint, only the variables get set differently depending what function app is going to be routed to.

Is there a way this xml content could be moved into a file where parameters can be passed through to then generate the XML for every API policy so we have the logic stored in only one place?

I have looked at a variety of uses of the file() function but can't see anything that could be done to achieve what I need here.

Thanks

Comment: When you have general logic for all operations of your API, you can set the policy on API level using the Terraform resource [azurerm_api_management_api_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_policy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `templatefile` function for that [1]. The `templatefile` function works in the following way:

> templatefile(path, vars)

Where the `path` represents the file location and the `vars` are a map of variables that will be used to replace the placeholders in the file itself. I will give an example based on the XML file you have. You would first create the template file inside of the same directory probably (e.g., `xml_content.tpl`):

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Key") == ${password})">
            <set-backend-service base-url="${hostname_url}" />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Key") != null)">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-body>An incorrect Key header has been passed in the request</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-backend-service base-url="${other-route-variable}" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Notice that I removed the `password` value and the data source output in `url`. Those will now expect variables with names `password` and `hostname_url` to be provided when using the `templatefile` function:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "api_put_policy" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.my_api.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.my_api.name
  operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.my_api.operation_id

    xml_content  = templatefile("${path.root}/xml_content.tpl", 
    password     = var.password
    hostname_url = data.azurerm_function_app.MyFunctionApp.default_hostname
  )
}
```

Whenever this is called, it will look for the placeholder values and replace them. Two additional things to note:

1. With the current setup, the `"${other-route-variable}"` would be required to be provided in the `templatefile` function call, otherwise it would fail.
2. The `path.root` option is built-in in Terraform [2].

In theory, if you were to create a module from this to make it more portable, then you would just have to change the `path` to the file so it can be provided through a variable probably.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Comment: Yup this approach worked perfectly! Thanks